# Cambiar un array por una consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

saludos no tengo un problema estoy calculando que desde la fecha de salida me sume xxx dias y me muestre segun la cantidad de dias la fecha que regresa sin contar fines de semana ni dias feriados.
de momento colocando los dias feriados en un array me funciona a la perfección.
pero tengo un detalle los dias feriados no los quiero dentro del array sino que sean consultados en la bd mysql pero no e conseguido que me funcione no se si me pueden orientar que estoy haciendo mal.

Si se corre el codigo tal cual como lo paso sin  ninguna modificación dira:

Salio 2020-12-12
En la presente fecha ya se han descontado los fines de semana y feriados
Debe regresar: 2021-02-02
Le Corresponden 33 Dias Habiles

y si hago el llamado a la consulta de mysql sale:

Salio 2020-12-12
En la presente fecha ya se han descontado los fines de semana y feriados
Debe regresar: 2021-01-27
Le Corresponden 33 Dias Habiles

por lo tanto no esta contando los 4 dias feriados que se encuentran entre esas fechas.

```
$fechaSalida = '2020-12-12';
$total='33';

//esta es la opcion que estoy incluyendo nueva para que me consulte las fechas en la bd 
// y no por el array

//**************//
/* Estructura de tabla para la tabla `fechas`
--

CREATE TABLE `fechas` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `fechas`
--

INSERT INTO `fechas` (`id`, `fecha`) VALUES
(3, '2020-03-24'),
(4, '2020-03-25'),
(5, '2020-04-18'),
(6, '2020-04-19'),
(7, '2020-05-01'),
(8, '2020-06-24'),
(9, '2020-07-05'),
(10, '2020-07-24'),
(11, '2020-10-12'),
(12, '2020-12-24'),
(13, '2020-12-25'),
(14, '2020-12-31'),
(15, '2021-01-01');

*/

/***********consulta a la base de datos

/*

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "recursos");
$sql = "SELECT fecha FROM fechas";
$result = $conexion -> query($sql);

$feriados = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row;

print_r($set);*/

//pero sigue sin leerme los dias feriados
//********************************************///


//con este array me funcioa bien el detalle esta en que se deben cambiar las fechas manuales desde codido y es lo que no quiero que pase, sino que cambien los datos en una interfaz por php.

$feriados = array( 
 '2021-01-01', //Año nuevo
 '2020-03-24', //lunes carnaval
 '2020-03-25', //martes carnaval
 '2020-04-18', //jueves santo
 '2020-04-19', //declaracion de independencia
 '2020-05-01', //Día del trabajador
 '2020-06-24', //Batalla de Carabobo
 '2020-07-05', //Día de la independencia
 '2020-07-24', //Natalicio de Simón Bolívar
 '2020-10-12', //Día de la Resistencia Indígena
 '2020-12-24', //Víspera de Navidad
 '2020-12-25', //Navidad
 '2020-12-31', //Fiesta de Fin de Año
); 



//le Asigno la fecha se salida para que comience a contar
$comienzo = strtotime($fechaSalida); 
//Inicializo la Fecha Final 
$fecha_venci_noti = $comienzo; 
//Inicializo El Contador 
$i = 0; while ($i < $total) { 
//Le Sumo un Dia a La Fecha Final que seria la fecha de regreso (86400 Segundos)
$fecha_venci_noti += 86400; 
//Inicializo a FALSE La Variable Para Saber Si Es Feriado 
$es_feriado = FALSE; //Recorro Todos Los Feriados 
foreach ($feriados as $key => $feriado) { 
//Verifico Si La Fecha Final Actual Es Feriado O No 

 if (date("Y-m-d", $fecha_venci_noti) === date("Y-m-d", strtotime($feriado))) { 
//En Caso de Ser feriado Cambio Mi variable A TRUE
  $es_feriado = TRUE; } } 
//Verifico Que No Sea Un Sabado, Domingo O Feriado
 if (!(date("w", $fecha_venci_noti) == 6 || date("w", $fecha_venci_noti) == 0 || $es_feriado)) { 
//En Caso De No Ser Sabado, Domingo O Feriado Aumentamos Nuestro contador 
$i++; } } 
//Convercion de los valores para verlos nuevamente en fecha.
$fecha=date("Y-m-d", $fecha_venci_noti); 
// anuncio del resulta es decir la fecha de regreso

echo '<br> Salio '.$fechaSalida;
echo '<br> En la presente fecha ya se han descontado los fines de semana y feriados';
echo '<br> Debe regresar: '.$fecha.'<br>';

echo 'Le Corresponden '.$total.' Dias Habiles <br>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas.

PRIMERO

La parte MySQL, o es orientada a objetos, o es procedual. Cualquiera sirve, pero [no deben ser combinadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples). En este caso usaré orientado a objetos.

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "recursos");
$sql = "SELECT fecha FROM fechas";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);
```

SEGUNDO

> $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

La línea no está incorrecta, pero para recorrer todas las filas de un objeto de base de datos mysql hay que hacer un llamado al mismo por cada registro hasta que llegue al final, a menos que sepas explicitamente que el resultado es solo un (1) registro.
Lo dicho, en código sería:

```
$feriados = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Se iterará sobre el objeto $result, una fila por ciclo, hasta que llegue al final
    $feriados[] = $row['fecha'];
}
```

Ahora, si, si haces un

```
print_r($feriados);
```

El resultado sería el array que estas buscando:

```
[0] => 2020-03-24
[1] => 2020-03-25
[2] => 2020-04-18
[3] => 2020-04-19
...
```

FINALMENTE

PHP tiene funciones avanzadas para [manejar fechas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y hacer operaciones aritméticas con ellas.

```
$f_ini = '2020-04-28'; // Valor de ejemplo
$dias_a_sumar = 2; // Valor de ejemplo

$f_fin = new DateTime($f_ini);
$f_fin->modify('+'.$dias_a_sumar.' day'); // Suma los dias suministrados
while(in_array($f_fin->format('N'), array(6, 7)) or in_array($f_fin->format('Y-m-d'), $feriados)) {
    // Mientras la fecha sea sabado (6), domingo (7); o esté en el array de $feriados
    $f_fin->modify('+1 day'); // Suma un día más a la fecha
}

echo 'La nueva fecha: ' . $f_fin->format('Y-m-d');
```

Testeando:

Para `dias_a_sumar = 3`, la salida es `2020-05-04` (dia del trabajo + sab + dom).
Para `dias_a_sumar = 2`, la salida es `2020-04-30`.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo me funciono le hice unos pequeños ajustes pero mas que todos para que me funcionara bien con el codigo que tengo y quedo fino muchas gracias si me di cuenta de algunas fallas que yo tenia. de verdad muchas gracias por el apoyo.